# MongoDB Count and groupby subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "url":"mysite.com",
    "views": 
     [
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"2.2.2.2","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"}
     ]
}
```

If i want to count how many unique ips (groupBy), how can I do that with mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired result. The aggregation pipeline will have a [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation as the first step which deconstructs the `views` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. The next pipeline stage [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) then groups the documents by the `"views.ip"` field, calculates the `count` field for each group, and outputs a document for each unique state.
The new per-ip documents have two fields: the `_id` field and the `count` field. The `_id` field contains the value of the unique IP address; i.e. the group by field. The `count` field is a calculated field that contains the total ip count per each unique IP. To calculate the value, [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) uses the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator to calculate the total number of IP addresses. So your final aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$views"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$views.ip",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "2.2.2.2",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "1.1.1.1",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

To get the total of all unique IP's, you need another [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline stage, this time the _id is null, that is you group all the documents from the previous pipeline stream into one, then use the same [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operation on that group to get the total of the count. The aggregation pipeline would look like this in the end:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$views"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$views.ip",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": {
                "$sum": "$count"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "total" : 4
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @Broshi No worries, glad to be of help.

Comment: Sorry for re-asking, but how can I sum 1 + 3 numbers to get a total of all the unique ip's? I dont want to iterate via PHP on it...or should i open a new question for it?

Comment: Is there an easy way to return a mix of both solutions in the same query? I mean, returning an array containing the number of counts per IP, and a last object containing the total count for all IPs. For example:
`[ 
        {
            "_id" : "2.2.2.2",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "1.1.1.1",
            "count" : 3
        }, { "_id": "total", "count": 4 }
    ]`

Comment: @charliebrownie Can you please create a new question for this?

Comment: my question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178741/mongodb-groupby-subdocument-and-count-add-total-count cc. @chridam